# Remove root via update

Tags: updates, root-access

I want to remove the root, i.e. unroot the phone Nexus 4. The automatic factory image downloader using Nexus toolkit takes ages (for some reason). I also read somewhere that updating your rooted phone removes the root. So How do I update a rooted android in order to remove the root?

Answer (score 0):

You simply flash a factory image. That overwrites the `/system` partition completely, effectively removing root.

For where to obtain those images, please take a look at [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/16575)

Answer (score 0):

Using nexus root toolkit, there is an unroot button, use that, then do a factory reset (and/or a reflash) if you want to.

After you have unrooted press lock, to lock the bootloader.